# Generating const arrays in C from a database

Tags: perl

I have to provide some C++ code consisting of `const` arrays initialised with well-known values.

More precisely, several arrays containing

- Between 0 and 255 strings for a text-based user interface
- Metadata, like lengths and positions of those strings
- Data representing a hierarchical menu structure
- Metadata connecting the menu structure with the strings and configuration data stored elsewhere

The menu items are accessed by their index in an array, and are related to other linked menu items, also accessed by index.

Here is the code I want to generate automatically from a better editable document:

```
/* gl_PsNMenuType holds one byte of metadata for each menu. This byte will describe
whether the menu only refers to a bunch of submenus or if it is a terminal item, where
the user actually can enter a setting to be saved */
const uint8_t gl_PsNMenuType[MAXMENUS] PROGMEM = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

/* gl_PsNMenuParent holds the index of each menu's parent menu. i.e. tree one step up */  
const uint8_t gl_PsNMenuParent[MAXMENUS] PROGMEM = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3};  // referenz auf den übergeordneten MP

/* gl_PsNMenuFixTexts is a list of identifiers text snippets which build the layout of 
the respective menu. The text snippets are stored in gl_PsFixTexts and the respective       
index of a text snippet is saved here. MFTS is a list sentinel*/
const uint8_t gl_PsNMenuFixTexts[MAXMENUS][MAXFIXTEXTSPM] PROGMEM = { 
  { 20, 2, MFTS}, // text snippets for menu 0
  {2, 9, 1, MFTS}, // for menu 1
  {2, 10, MFTS}, //2
  {2, 11, MFTS}, //3
  {2, 13, MFTS} //4

};

/* gl_PsNMenuParentListText holds the identifiers of the text snippets which shall be
displayed by the parent menu while selection before descending to the submenus. There's
one such snippet for each menu. */
const uint8_t gl_PsNMenuParentListText[MAXMENUS] PROGMEM = { 0, 9, 10, 11, 13};  

/* gl_PsNMenuFtPos closely relates to gl_PsNMenuFixTexts. The positions on the display
for each text snippet of a menu are stored here. */ 
const uint8_t gl_PsNMenuFtPos[MAXMENUS][MAXFIXTEXTSPM] PROGMEM = {  // Liste der Fixtextpositionen
  { 0, 5, MFTS, MFTS, MFTS}, // 0
  { 0, 5, MFTS, MFTS, MFTS}, // 1
  { 0, 5, MFTS, MFTS, MFTS},  // 2
  { 0, 5, MFTS, MFTS, MFTS},  // 3
  { 0, 5, MFTS, MFTS, MFTS},  // 4
};

/* gl_PsNMenuChildren stores the indices of all submenus reachable from a certain menu 
this is essentially the structure of the menu tree MAXMENUS is used for array size and 
also as sentinel*/
const uint8_t gl_PsNMenuChildren[MAXMENUS][MAXMENUCHILDREN] PROGMEM = {
  { 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, MAXMENUS},  // 0
  { 4, 7, 8, 9, MAXMENUS},    // 1
  {1, MAXMENUS}, //2
  {1, MAXMENUS}, // 3
  {3, 5, 6, MAXMENUS}  // 4
};

/* finally the text snippets */
const uint8_t gl_PsFixTexts[MAXFIXTEXTS][MAXFIXTEXTLEN] PROGMEM = {
  {5, 0x54, 0x65, 0x73, 0x74, 0x31 },  // 0: Test1
  {9, 0x62, 0x6c, 0x61, 0x62, 0x6c, 0x61, 0x62, 0x6c, 0x62 }, // 1: bla
  {4, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x6e, 0x75},  // 2: Menu
  {4, 0x4d, 0x61, 0x69, 0x6e}, // 20: Main
  {4, 0x65, 0x78, 0x69, 0x74}, // 21: exit
  {4, 0x62, 0x61, 0x63, 0x6b}  // 22: back
};
```

This is shortened for brevity and dysfunctional in this state.

As the contents of those arrays are exclusively `uint8_t` characters it would be much simpler to write the data automatically, while ensuring that the referencing indices are all correct.

I want some other data describing the menu structure in a more elaborate but maintainable way.

I thought about making a spreadsheet where I could show the hierarchy across the columns and enter all the data. Then some tool would be needed to break down the hierarchy.

I hope someone can let me know of any tools that are suitable for this task. If there's nothing available then I have to write a Perl conversion program. Are there any useful CPAN libraries?

Edit: some further explanation of the use of the arrays

This data will be utilised by an user interface function, which is rather simplicistic. There will be an identifier pointing to the actual menu entry, which is edited or viewed by the user. This identifier will be used as index wherever MAXMENUS is defining the array size. these arrays describe the look and feel of every menu entry. The menu entries refer to different strings (gl_PsFixTexts) and positions (gl_PsNMenuFtPos) which declare, how and where to display strings when processing a certain menu entry. 
The most important arrays are gl_PsNMenuParent and gl_PsNMenuChildren which point to the menu entries above and below in hierarchy. This is, how the code will let the user navigate through the menu structure.
There's also some information if this is an terminal entry in the menu tree, i.e. if there's some data to change, which again means modifying a setting for the software.

Comment: If it was me, I'd simply write a piece of C or C++ that parses the CSV and generates the C-code needed. But then I'm a bit bizarre like that, and prefer to do things in a language I know well (especially when it turns out I already have a decent .csv reader - it may need tweaking depending on exactly what .csv format you are using, but shouldn't be too hard).

Comment: And I'd much prefer `{ 9, "blablabla" },`

Comment: I found your question very difficult to read as it is so wordy. I've removed about half of the bulk, but please check it to make sure that it still expresses what you want to say. You are welcome to roll it back to your original if you prefer. Even after that, I'm not entirely clear what it is that you need and, jusdging by the lack of solutions, so are many other people

Comment: @Borodin You quite got the point. To make it clear: At the end of the day I have to hack all the information about the menu structure into a table, database or c++ code directly. But the crucial point is to keep it maintainable. And once written down as arrays, it is not. So I'm on the lookout for a beautiful layout and a tool which converts that layouted data into ugly arrays.

Comment: @MatsPetersson *LOL*. I never checked if the character tables of my display correlate with ASCII for at least alphanumeric characters. I should have, I guess. And I'll probably stick to PEARL, when I have to write some tool myself. There's a usable parser (Text::CSV) at cpan.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: Unfortunately, the compiler refuses to initialise a uint8_t array with a const char* string. *sigh* perhaps I have to change it all over.

Comment: Please, it's *“Perl”*. Even “PERL” will upset those of us with delicate sensibilities. The language *was* going to be called “Pearl” but the author found that there was already a language by that name.

Comment: Is the data something you could express in JSON, or even XML? What I am missing here is an understanding of what all this stuff *means*

Comment: @Borodin sorry. Perl, Perl, Perl. Keyboard doesn't make the noise of chalk on a blackboard :). I'm not really awake, yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my best answer, based on what you have told us.

Menu information like that is commonly stored as XML. An XML data file would allow you to relate menu items to their text labels and their children quite expressively.

In the end you could write a GUI front end that would present that XML in a graphical form and allow you as much facility and complexity as want to write.

In the end, it is the XML file that is the authority on the interface structure, and which can be converted very easily with Perl to any format that you desire.

Also, following on from what `@MatsPetersson` said in his comment, I would *much* rather see

```c++
{9, 'b', 'l', 'a', 'b', 'l', 'a', 'b', 'l', 'a'}, // 1: blablabla
```

which is certain to be acceptable to as a `uint8_t []` initialiser.

If you want further help then you will have to expand your description with a line-by-line explanation of what your *"desired output"* means in English.

Comment: I edited the code sample to make the purpose of each array clear. Using XML to describe a hierarchy of elements sounds very reasonable. If editing the XML by vim or a XML editor is applicable, I think it might be sufficient to do that and convert the XML-file into c++-code in a single run. I'm going to read some XML-tutorial, I guess.

Comment: Ok. This is what I try to do now: I'm going to write a XML document representing the menu hierarchy with all relevant elements in a suitable editor (trying jEdit at the moment). Then I code a Perl script which will read this document using XML::Simple and writes the c++ arrays into a file. Let's see how far I get this way. I must admit, using a spreadsheet to define a menu structure was a really stupid idea. Hence your answer got me on the right track.

Comment: No! Not `XML::Simple`! Even the author has succumbed and added a note to the module's documentation saying not to use it for new code. It's horrible, really. I recommend you go for `XML::LibXML` or `XML::Twig`. The spreadsheet wasn't a bad idea, but XML is good at representing hierarchical data and is commonly used for GUI specifications.

Comment: Ok, I installed LibXML, and it seems to read my XML, but how to use it? The documentation and most tutorials are all greek to me. I guess, I'll need some weeks to master it.

Comment: You may find `XML::Twig` a little simpler. The documentation isn't spread out across multiple files in the same way.

Comment: Another point about [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML::Twig) - for your purposes you should ignore the parts about processing an XML document incrementally via callbacks, and instead simply call `parsefile` and process the resulting document object. There's also an [online tutorial and FAQ](http://www.xmltwig.org/xmltwig)